# Stop fancybox from using an empy placeholder on images in a gallery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox to turn a grid of images on page into a gallery when you click on one.  They are all linked together with the rel="gallery" property.  The issue is when you click on one of the images, fancybox is putting a blank placeholder div in it's place, causing all the images to shift in the background.  When you close fancybox, it puts it back onto the page with a display none.

I eventually just caved and put a display:block!important on my a tags so they would come back up, and I'm about to put some generic style that is the size of my images onto the stupid empty placeholder it throws down.

The fancybox demo site doesn't even function like this.  It leaves the a tags wrapping the images alone... Is there a way to stop fancybox from doing this?

Click on the "photos" tab here for a live example. *REMOVED LINK.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave the `href` attribute **empty** like you did :

```
<a rel="gallery" class="gallery" href=""><img src="../images/placeholder_prop.jpg"></a>
```

then fancybox will consider the whole `<a>` tag as the *target* content and will move it into the box as `inline` content (leaving a placeholder behind)

You just need to fill up the `href` attribute with the targeted `image` like :

```
<a rel="gallery" class="gallery" href="../images/placeholder_prop.jpg"><img src="../images/placeholder_prop.jpg"></a>
```

so only such targeted `image` will be displayed without messing with your html document.

Comment: Doh.  Didn't even notice.  That fixed it, Thanks!